# Query from RealmList<String> in RealmObject

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a list of object of `Product` type as follows.

```
public class Product extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String productId;

    private String name;

    private RealmList<String> tags;

    public Product(String productId, String name, RealmList<String> tags) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.name = name;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RealmList<String> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(RealmList<String> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "productId='" + productId + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", tags=" + tags +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The array `tags` can have options like `['T01', 'T02', 'T03', 'T04']`.

How to query to get a `List` of objects with the value `'T01'` from a list of `Product` objects?

Also, rather than querying for each tag, is there a way to query from multiple tags at the same time? TIA.

Comment: You need to nag Realm to add support for this https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513 here

Comment: And also here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361 preferably both

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Lol yes, I found these too. Can't believe it's still not there.

Comment: I knooooooooooow. There was a survey asking "what feature do you hope to see in Realm", I said primitive list queries! I guess just being the one person asking for it wasn't enough :p